# Java Moving files across drives causes DirectoryNotEmptyException

Tags: java, swing, exception

I have created a simple java program that in a nutshell takes two directories and then moves one to another. The program works fine unless I try to move files across different drives, then in causes java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException even though it doesn't mind non-empty directories otherwise (in fact I need it to move everything inside of it).

```
try {
        Files.move(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Files.move(file, cgbaFile.getParent(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

For the target, you're providing the directory you want to move the file into. This is incorrect. The target should be the new pathname that you want the file to have--the new directory plus the filename.

For example, suppose you wanted to move `/tmp/foo.txt to the /var/tmp` directory. You're calling `Files.move("/tmp/foo.txt", "/var/tmp")` when you should be calling `Files.move("/tmp/foo.txt", "/var/tmp/foo.txt")`.

You're getting that specific error because the JVM is trying to delete the target directory in order to replace it with the file.

One of these ought to generate the correct target path:

```
Path target = cgbaFile.resolveSibling(file.getFileName());

Path target = cgbaFile.getParent().resolve(file.getFileName());
```